# Incrementing a filename if the file already exists VB.NET to C# conversion

Tags: c#

I am currently rewriting some software i created from VB.NET to C# due to additional image analysis functions and filters that are not possible in VB.NET. Part of the program automatically creates a new folder for the day if one does not already exist (that works fine) and it is then supposed to start saving images stored in the image buffer of the camera to file while incrementing the file name. I am not entirely sure if i am using the correct method here as i am trying to convert from VB.NET.

```
        private void tmAutoCap_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (dAltitudeAngle < Convert.ToDouble(tbSolarAltSet.Text) & cbDarkSubAC.Checked == true)
        {

            try
            {
                ImageBuffer ImgBuffer = default(ImageBuffer);
                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;
                int BytesPerLine = 0;
                Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;


                int i = 0;
                string FileMask = (Global_Variables.NewDirectory + "\\AutoCap_{0}.bmp");
                string Filename = "";
                Filename = string.Format(FileMask, i);

                while (System.IO.File.Exists(Filename))
                {
                    i += 1;
                    Filename = string.Format(FileMask, i);
                }

                Bitmap Dark = Image.FromFile(tbDarkRoot.Text, true) as Bitmap;
                ImgBuffer = IcImagingControl1.ImageBuffers[1];
                // Calculate the count of bytes ber line using the color format and the
                // pixels per line of the image buffer.
                BytesPerLine = (ImgBuffer.BitsPerPixel / 8) * ImgBuffer.PixelPerLine - 1;
                for (y = 0; y <= ImgBuffer.Lines - 1; y++)
                {
                    for (x = 0; x <= BytesPerLine; x++)
                    {
                        if (Dark.GetPixel(x, y).R <= ImgBuffer[x, y])
                        {
                            ImgBuffer[x, y] = Convert.ToByte(ImgBuffer[x, y] - Dark.GetPixel(x, y).R);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ImgBuffer[x, y] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                ImgBuffer.SaveAsBitmap(Filename);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Application.UserAppDataPath + "\\SkyCamErrorLog.txt", string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", Environment.NewLine, DateTime.Now.ToString(), Environment.NewLine, ex.ToString()));

            }
```

I had expected this to look for files and if it found any then automatically increment from the highest file already there by use of the filemask but it always fails to create any file and the error message thrown out is:

```
TIS.Imaging.ICException: Unknown error occurred Base Library Error : Permission denied
at TIS.Imaging.ImageBuffer.SaveImage(String filename)
at TIS.Imaging.ImageBuffer.SaveAsBitmap(String filename)
at Sky_Cam_Version_2.SkyCamForm.tmAutoCap_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

For this reason i believe there is something wrong with the way i am trying to create the filename.

Comment: Don't use single `&` in your if-statement. Use double `&&`.

Comment: And are you sure that the directory is writeable?

Comment: Finally, when debugging this, it's probably best to print out the filename it is using so you can tell if it is doing what you are expecting. Or use a breakpoint to check before it creates the file.

Comment: You need to [learn how to use a debugger](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to look at the value of `Filename`.

Comment: I edited to the &&
I have write access to the directory as i can use another function of the software to write image files to the same location
I used the breakpoint already and the result of filename is always what i expect it to be with no currently existing files "AutoCap_0.bmp"

Comment: It actually seems the problem is not in this code specifically as it is actually doing it's job correctly, the real issue seems to be in my use of global variable which seems to function differently in C# to what i was used to in VB.NET

Comment: @Purgitoria how so? Is it changing somewhere else? Are you sure it is actually global?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was not so much in the code here as it was actually doing the right thing. The issue was elsewhere in the code where i defined "NewDirectory" i had the code simply as

```
var NewDirectory = (tbSaveFilesLocation.Text + "\\" + NewFolder);
```

What i should have had is what i have now which actually defines the global variable so i can call it from elsewhere.

```
Global_Variables.NewDirectory = (tbSaveFilesLocation.Text + "\\" + NewFolder);
```

It is set as a global variable as the directory is created based on a timer. When the timer ticks it looks to see if a directory exists with the current date/time and if it does not it creates a new folder and this then becomes the folder that all new images should be saved to.

The debugger was showing me the answer i just couldn't see it for looking as i was so focused on the output of "\AutoCap_{0}.bmp" which returned a correct result i forgot that it should have had the results of Global_Variables.NewDirectory in front of it therefor it was trying to write a file with the correct name but without any directory referenced.